# Healthy teeth by kiddush levana

Tags: chabad, kiddush-levanah, teeth

R' Menachem Mendel Schneerson, z"l would write to people that a Segula for healthy teeth is connected to kiddush Levana

Does anyone know the source of such a concept?

Side point: many times by kiddush Levana he would touch his teeth.

Comment: How do you know he would write people this? How do you know he would touch his teeth? Please [edit] to clarify and don't place the info in a comment.

Comment: Several Hassidic sources [here](http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=5887&CategoryID=1282) (haven't read them through)

Answer (score 1):

The [Taamei Haminhagim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&pgnum=216) says that "saying 'And I shouldn't have a toothache' after 'My enemies shouldn't touch me for evil' is a Segulah against toothache" is from Reb Yisroel Ruzhiner.

[Some](https://amhasefer.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%A6%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9C-%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%91-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D/#comment-344) say that it's in the Siddur Yaavetz.

I found it in the "[Siddur Beis Yaakov](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42760&st=&pgnum=445)" (though only in brackets and Rashi script, and is from 1881). but not in [Siddur Yaavetz](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22619&st=&pgnum=28) (which was printed in Altuna in 1747 - during R' Yaakov Emden's lifetime and within his city).

So you should probably take the source which links it to Reb Yaakov Emden with a grain of salt[1].

[1]. Also, to note that the comment linking Reb Yaakov Emden to this Segula also says that the connection seems weak.

Comment: It is unclear what the "it" is that is the segula. The Ta'amei Haminhagim says that the segula is to say "ולא יהיה לי כאב  שיניים" but that does not appear in your answer, and the only thing mentioned in the question is touching your teeth which is not mentioned in the Ta'amei Haminhagim.

Comment: I meant that the only specific thing mentioned is touching your teeth, as if that might be what the segula is. Your answer still doesn't tell us what the segula is. While you can technically answer the question of "what's the source of a connection between a segula for healthy teeth and Kiddush Levana?" without mentioning what the segula is, it seems a shame to leave it out when it's right there in the Ta'amei Haminhagim, especially when people might assume that the segula is touching your teeth since that's what was mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a Chabad Minhag to do so. See this:

https://asktherav.com/15209-is-this-true-that-kiddush-levana-is-a-segulah-for-ones-teeth/