# Pulling ear when sneeze

Tags: minhag, history, sources-mekorot, provenance

Where does it come from that people pull their ear when they sneeze does it have something to do with our forefather Jacob before him no-one became ill just before death? That is, he became ill before he died so that he could call his sons in and bless them and to arrange his affairs befor he died. Before that, people would sneeze and die.

Comment: Can you source this practice?  I've never seen this before.  Can you source "our forfather Jacob that he sneezed and died"?

Comment: No I can't I don't know if it is even true I wrote it only to help trigger someone's memory

Comment: Because I think I once heard both those concepts together

Comment: I know someone who pulls his ear when he has the hiccups. He claims it stops the hiccups. I asked him if Pavlov taught him that. In any case, this type of question really really needs more foundation than as is presented.

Comment: http://www.chabadtalk.com/forum/showthread.php3?t=7290

Comment: Thank you danno I think this will help I did not read it.

Comment: All of it yet.........

Comment: Without any reason to think this has to do with Judaism, I think this is off topic.

Comment: If you would read the link that danno posted you would realize that it is based in judisim

Comment: @menachem danno's comment is not in the question.

Comment: @DoubleAA http://www.chabadtalk.com/forum/attachment.php3?s=230caae23eef50af6b34b78b595d32ca&attachmentid=1057&d=1151992119

Comment: While I'm not a doctor, I can tell you what a doctor has told me about sinus problems, somewhat. One of the reasons to blow your nose when your nose is stuffed is not merely to eliminate the phlegm. It is to alleviate pressure on the Eustachian tubes which go to your ears. When you sneeze, the pressure from the sneeze itself goes to these tubes, also. Thus, pulling on your ears is one means to dissipate the pressure.

Comment: @menachem do not assume that (a) comments last forever or (b) everybody reads them.  Anything important to your question should be [edit]ed into it.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out and you give me an example or something and it's question that I should have added

Comment: @MonicaCellio Same applies to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71091/healthy-teeth-by-kiddush-levana#comment206289_71091

Comment: This sounds like a question for the Ba'al Itush Behalacha http://forum.otzar.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=10218&hilit=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this source](https://books.google.com/books?id=PO3wZ-BBFzIC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=pulling%20you%20ear%20after%20sneezing&source=bl&ots=AvFZSAwioj&sig=chr7XKifHbL3z7ZMU8-V30gB0NI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgq7ef1c3MAhUEFT4KHXfCChoQ6AEIXzAJ#v=onepage&q=pulling%20you%20ear%20after%20sneezing&f=false), it is a *bubbe meisse*

The custom was common among Jews from Lithuania and Galicia. The ear pulling was done when someone sneezed while speaking about a dead person. Some people always pulled one or both ears after sneezing and said, *Tzu lange mazaldikke yohrn* - "To long, lucky years".

I've never seen this done to anyone including myself, and my grandparents were Galicianer. See my medical comment above, as to why I think pulling the ears may have a medical benefit. I'll ask my doctor if doing this may reduce the chances of deafness, (assuming he'll listen to my theory :-)

Comment: Yes. The result of this practice is  that whether or not your years are lengthened, your **ears** will certainly get longer!

Comment: http://www.aish.com/j/fs/Jew-Perstitions.html?tab=y  also addresses "pulling one' sears" and other superstitions.

Comment: Carol Burnett may have had the right id"ears" all along!

Answer (score 1):

According to R. Menashe Klein, it is assur to do this because it is chukot akum (which I imagine in this case means nonsense. From this [important forum](http://forum.otzar.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=10218&hilit=) on the topic):

> משנה הלכות חי"ב סי' קלז: ניחוש להמתעטש למשוך תנוך אזן
>
> לכבוד ידידי היקר וכו' הי"ו
>
> אחדשה"ט.
>
> מה שהביא מנהג כשאדם מתעטש (ניס"ן בלע"ז או סני"ז) מושך תנוך אזנו.
>
> לפענ"ד אין זה מנהג ישראל ועכ"פ לאו מנהג ותיקין ובגמ' ברכות (נ"ג ע"א)
>   אמרו של בית ר"ג לא היו אומרים מרפא בבית המדרש מפני בטול בית המדרש
>   ועיין רש"י שרגילים לומר אסותא והוא בפדר"א פ' נ"ב מיום שנבראו שמים וארץ
>   לא היה אדם חולה וכו' לפיכך חייב אדם לומר בעטישתו חיים שנהפך המות לחיים
>   ע"ש ובגשה"ס ציין עליו ועיין יו"ד סי' רמ"ו סי"ז. והנה לומר אסותא שהוא
>   לרפואה שמענו אבל מה לי משיכת האוזן ואין לעשות כן כי הוא מדרכי גוים.
>
> דושה"ט בלב ונפש,
>
> מנשה הקטן

Comment: See also http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2604&st=&pgnum=127&hilite=